# Gerar arquivos com todas as permissões

Tags: java, arquivo, permissões

Estou gerando arquivos *.csv a partir disso:

```
BufferedWriter strW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(caminhoCSV.toString()))
```

Porém os arquivos gerados estão apenas com permissão de leitura, como poderia alterar isso para que o arquivo gerado tivesse permissão de leitura e de alteração?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes usar mesmo a classe *File* depois de gerado o arquivo

```
String caminho = "caminho/do/meu/arquivo";

final File file = new File(caminho);
file.setReadable(true, false);
file.setExecutable(true, false);
file.setWritable(true, false);
```

Comment: `final File` é necessário ou só `File` é suficiente?

Comment: não necessariamente precisa ser `final` mas use para garantir que você não está modificando o valor indevidamente

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou como precisava +1

Answer (score 1):

Você pode chamar o comando do unix, se estiver utilizando um O.S baseado nele, através do Runtime.exec, observe:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 666 caminho_arquivo");
```

Tenha cuidado ao concatenar uma string, tem que ter um espaço entre o 666 e o caminho do arquivo.

Comment: poderia explicar como esse comando funciona?

Comment: Certeza de que isso funciona independente do sistema operacional?

Comment: R. Santos, chmod é um comando do unix pra alterar as permissões de um arquivo, existem diversos 'números' que representam as permissões do arquivo, envolvendo permissões de grupo, permissões públicas, ler, gravar e executar, etc. Quando você executa essa linha de código que eu lhe passei, você está executando um comando shell, e este comando, como já explicado, está alterando a permissão de um arquivo (666, no caso, é ler e gravar em todos os níveis). Acho que todos sistemas operacionais baseados no unix possuem esse sistema.

Comment: Se executar no windows não funcionará, e como na pergunta não está claro que se trata de linux, é bom você editar a resposta contendo esta informação.

Comment: Eu percebi isso, editei a resposta já, obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado pela dica mas como necessariamente não precisa ser linux o ambiente onde a aplicação será executada irá haver inconsistências +1